# How can i automate sharepoint people picker with watin

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, watin

I'm new in automated testing (Watin for IE) and i came across with some issues automating the People picker of sharepoint. I can't take the controls within the pop up because the pop up blocks main page (blocking also Intenet Explorer Developer Tools). Someone knows how can i do it or at least the name of the controls for IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is a modal dialog that is getting you bothered, you can try this. 
Open the SharePoint site in Firefox and then open the People-Picker. In firefox you would have the URL displayed for the modal dialog too. And from there you use the URL to open it in a new browser tab directly and use a web development tools plugin to view the DOM.